# How to monitor passenger with monit

Tags: monitoring, phusion-passenger, monit

I want to set up monit to monitor passenger but everything I've found so far has basically said just monitor your website using monit. If possible I'd like to monitor passenger directly so I have more control over it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to monitor passenger, or apache?

For apache, there's an entry in the stock /etc/monit/monitrc that you can pretty much use as is:

```
#  check process apache with pidfile /usr/local/apache/logs/httpd.pid
#    start program = "/etc/init.d/httpd start" with timeout 60 seconds
#    stop program  = "/etc/init.d/httpd stop"
#    if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
#    if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
#    if totalmem > 200.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
#    if children > 250 then restart
#    if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
#    if failed host www.tildeslash.com port 80 protocol http
#       and request "/monit/doc/next.php"
#       then restart
#    if failed port 443 type tcpssl protocol http
#       with timeout 15 seconds
#       then restart
#    if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
#    depends on apache_bin
#    group server
```

Comment: I'm already monitoring apache I want to monitor the resources used by passenger directly.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Which resources?